# Is there a way to make readExternal() use another constructor?

Tags: java, serialization, externalizable

I was trying to implement `readExternal` from the `Externalizable` interface in order to serialize my big object more efficiently when I realised there is no way I can make a new object (and use it) within that method. The point is that my efficient representation needs to be deciphered and therefore I can't assign my fields directly. The code looks as follows:

```
public class BigObject implements Externalizable {

    //lots of fields and methods...

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(this.encode()); //encodes to a BigInteger
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        BigInteger code = (BigInteger) in.readObject();
        BigObject bo = BigObject.decode(code);
        // now I would like this to be "bo"
    }
}
```

For now I copy all fields from the object I get, but it looks ugly and I wanted to know whether there would be a nicer way to something like this?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that your `encode` and `decode` methods are not consistent. The `decode` is a static method and `encode` is not. My suggestion will be to make `decode` non static.

Comment: I don't think you are answering my question. I have a working solution, but I would just like to make it nicer. Besides that, I don't see how I could make `decode(BigInteger code)` non-static...

Comment: Does the `decode` method belongs to code written by you? Can you show its structure?